# Outputting tag pairs such as images/files with Stash

Tags: stash

I'm getting into Stash and I wondered what the best way of handling tag pairs such as files/images?

My aim is to totally separate out the markup from the fetching of stuff from the database (exp:channel:entries tags etc). So far, this is how I'm currently handling it, and it works fine:

**Model end of things** (this would be within exp:channel:entries tag also with a load of other stuff).

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="main_image" parse_tags="yes"}
{my_image}
    {stash:url}{url}{/stash:url}
    {stash:height}{height}{/stash:height}
    {stash:width}{width}{/stash:width}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
{/my_image}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

**Markup end of things**

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="main_image"}
<img src="{url}" height="{height}" width="{width}" alt="{title}" title="{title}" />
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

What concerns me the most is I'm using a list even though there will only ever be one thing in it, as thus it makes me a bit uneasy.

Is there a better way of doing it? Like I said it definitely works, I just want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance point of view I don't see anything wrong with that at all. It will still output your desired variables. The `set_list` tag pair ideally caters for an array of items (many) but it should be just as happy returning one.

You could just set them as regular stash:set variables but it shouldn't make any difference performance wise either way.