# Storing multiple variables from CE Image tag pair in Stash

Tags: stash, ce-image

I'm attempting to store several variables generated by CE Image's Pair tag, as follows:

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:ce_img:pair src="{source_image}"}
       {stash:ee_img_original_width'}{width_orig}{/stash:ee_img_original_width}
       {stash:ee_img_sized_src'}{made}{/stash:ee_img_sized_src}
       {stash:ee_img_sized_width'}{width}{/stash:ee_img_sized_width}
    {/exp:ce_img:pair}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

I've reviewed [this post about getting a single var from CE Image](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11426/parse-order-fun-getting-a-stashed-assets-image-resized-using-ce-image-inside-a), and this one, about [grabbing multiple variables from a different tag pair](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9222/outputting-tag-pairs-such-as-images-files-with-stash), but I'm not getting anywhere. Thanks in advance!

**Corrected Syntax, Per Nate/Mark's Feedback**

```
<h2>Set Vars</h2>
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:ce_img:pair src="{source_image}"}
        {stash:ee_img_original_width}{width_orig}{/stash:ee_img_original_width}
        {stash:ee_img_sized_src}{made}{/stash:ee_img_sized_src}
        {stash:ee_img_sized_width}{width}{/stash:ee_img_sized_width}
    {/exp:ce_img:pair}
{/exp:stash:set}

<h2>Get Vars</h2>
<p>
    Original Width: {exp:stash:get name='ee_img_original_width'}<br>
    Path to New Image: {exp:stash:get name='ee_img_sized_src'}<br>
    New Image Width {exp:stash:get name='ee_img_sized_width'}
</p>
```

Comment: Looks like you have an extra single quote on the opening side of the stash vars.

Comment: Yep what Nate said (sorry nate just spotted your comment after answering below).

Comment: CE Image for me is typically presentation. The only thing I stash is the source image. Then when displaying it, I use CE Image

Comment: My goodness, it's been one of those days... thank you gentlemen! Jérôme Coupé, in this instance I'm building an embed that will perform some logic to generate retina resolution copies of the images, which requires some logic involving the widths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extraneous single quote ' in each of your opening tag pairs.

```
{stash:ee_img_original_width'}{width_orig}{/stash:ee_img_original_width}
```

Should be:

```
{stash:ee_img_original_width}{width_orig}{/stash:ee_img_original_width}
```